# Matching two path elements using javascript regex to make the right hand side greedy

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to match this.

```
/1234/5678
/1234
```

Into A and B, where the B is optional using this regular expression.

`/.*\/(?<A>\d+)(\/(?<B>.+?))?$/.exec("/1234/5678").groups;`

I want A=1234, and B=5678 when the path contains two parts, and when there's only one part, then just match `A`.

How do I make the optional /5678 greedy so that it matches if it's there, but still matches A if it's not.

```
/1234/5678 (A=1234, B=5678)
/1234 (A=1234, B=undefined)
```

Comment: try something like this? `\/(?<A>\d+)(?:\/(?<B>\d+))?$` see at https://regex101.com/r/6nil6L/latest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this.

```js
console.log(/(?:\/(?<A>[^\/]+))?(?:\/(?<B>[^\/]+))?/.exec("/1234/5678").groups);
console.log(/(?:\/(?<A>[^\/]+))?(?:\/(?<B>[^\/]+))?/.exec("/1234").groups);
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no need in a regular expression, you can just split the string and use array destructuring:

```js
{
 const [_, A, B] = '/1234/5678'.split('/');
 console.log({A, B});
}
{
 const [_, A, B] = '/1234'.split('/');
 console.log({A, B});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to match empty strings, you can make the second part including the `/` and the named group optional

```
\/(?<A>\d+)(?:\/(?<B>\d+))?
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Zfamqd/1)

```js
const strings = [
  "/1234/5678",
  "/1234",
  ""
];
const regex = /\/(?<A>\d+)(?:\/(?<B>\d+))?/;

strings.forEach(str => {
  if ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    console.log(m.groups);
  }
});
```